# how to parse multiple arrays from single json object and store them in Sqlite database in android

Tags: android, json, sqlite

how to parse multiple arrays from single json object and store them in Sqlite database in android
    **Actual JSOn data**

```
{
  "cityMasterEntity": [//// JSon array 1
    {
      "CityId": 1,
      "CityName": "Ahmedabad",
      "CreatedDate": "\/Date(1373091319697+0530)\/",
      "IsActive": true,
      "StateId": 6,
      "StateName": "Gujarat\u000d\u000a",
      "UpdatedDate": null
    },
    {
      "CityId": 3,
      "CityName": "Rajkot",
      "CreatedDate": "\/Date(1373091319697+0530)\/",
      "IsActive": true,
      "StateId": 6,
      "StateName": "Gujarat\u000d\u000a",
      "UpdatedDate": null
    },
    {
      "CityId": 2,
      "CityName": "Surat",
      "CreatedDate": "\/Date(1373091319697+0530)\/",
      "IsActive": true,
      "StateId": 6,
      "StateName": "Gujarat\u000d\u000a",
      "UpdatedDate": null
    }
  ],
  "countryMasterEntity": [ ////Json Array 2 
    {
      "CountryId": 1,             ///>>  i am not able parse and store this array in database 
      "CountryName": "India",
      "CreatedDate": "\/Date(1373091319697+0530)\/",
      "IsActive": true,
      "UpdatedDate": null
    }
  ],
```

This my code where i m expriencing problem

```
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) { 
    progressdialog.dismiss(); 
    System.out.println("JSONObject is"+result); 
    try { 
         citymaster = result.getJSONArray("cityMasterEntity"); 
         for(int i=0;i<citymaster.length();i++) { 
              result =citymaster.getJSONObject(i); 
              valuesCity.put("_id", i + 1); 
              int cityid1 = result.getInt("CityId"); 
              valuesCity.put("cityid", cityid1); 
              String cityname1 = result.getString("CityName"); 
              valuesCity.put("cityname", cityname1); 
              String createddate1 = result.getString("CreatedDate");
              valuesCity.put("createddate", createddate1); 
              String isactive1 = result.getString("IsActive"); 
              valuesCity.put("isactive", isactive1); 
              int stateid1 = result.getInt("StateId"); 
              valuesCity.put("stateid", stateid1); 
              String statename1 = result.getString("StateName"); 
              valuesCity.put("statename", statename1); 
              String updateddate1 = result.getString("UpdatedDate");
              valuesCity.put("updateddate", updateddate1);
              newrummydb.insert(Database.DATABASE_TABLE, null, valuesCity); 
        }

    countrymaster=result.getJSONArray("countryMasterEntity");/// >>>problem is in this line  
        for (int j=0;j<countrymaster.length();j++)
        {
             result =countrymaster.getJSONObject(j);// This line also
             valuesCountry.put("_id", j + 1);

             int countryid2 = result.getInt("CountryId");
                 valuesCountry.put(countryid, countryid2);
             String countryname2 = result.getString("CountryName");
             valuesCountry.put(countryname, countryname2);
             String createddate2 = result.getString("CreatedDate");
             valuesCountry.put(Ccreateddate, createddate2);
             String isactive2 = result.getString("IsActive");
             valuesCountry.put(Cisactive, isactive2);
             String updateddate2 = result.getString("UpdatedDate");
             valuesCountry.put(Cupdateddate, updateddate2);
             newrummydb.insert(Database.DATABASE_TABLE_COUNTRY, null, 
        }
```

**This my logcat**

```
     04-17 13:13:59.922: E/SQLiteDatabase(30756): Error inserting stateid=6 isactive=true _id=1 statename=Gujarat
        04-17 13:13:59.922: E/SQLiteDatabase(30756):  updateddate=null createddate=/Date(1373091319697+0530)/ cityname=Ahmedabad cityid=1
        04-17 13:13:59.922: E/SQLiteDatabase(30756): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: column _id is not unique (code 19)
        04-17 13:13:59.922: E/SQLiteDatabase(30756):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
        04-17 13:13:59.922: E/SQLiteDatabase(30756):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:775)
        04-17 13:13:59.922: E/SQLiteDatabase(30756):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
        04-17 13:13:59.922: E/SQLiteDatabase(30756):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
        04-17 13:13:59.922: E/SQLiteDatabase(30756):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
        04-17 13:13:59.922: E/SQLiteDatabase(30756):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
        04-17 13:13:59.922: E/SQLiteDatabase(30756):    at 

     com.example.newrummyjson.NewRummyActivity$JSONParsing.onPostExecute(NewRummyActivity.java:201)
        04-17 14:38:41.934: E/SQLiteDatabase(21980):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
        04-17 14:38:41.934: E/SQLiteDatabase(21980):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
        04-17 14:38:41.934: E/SQLiteDatabase(21980):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
        04-17 14:38:41.934: E/SQLiteDatabase(21980):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        04-17 14:38:41.934: E/SQLiteDatabase(21980):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        04-17 14:38:41.934: E/SQLiteDatabase(21980):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        04-17 14:38:41.934: E/SQLiteDatabase(21980):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        04-17 14:38:41.934: E/SQLiteDatabase(21980):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        04-17 14:38:41.934: E/SQLiteDatabase(21980):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        04-17 14:38:41.934: E/SQLiteDatabase(21980):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        04-17 14:38:41.934: E/SQLiteDatabase(21980):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You're inserting `_id` values that are already in the database. The question doesn't really have the required information to help you fix that.

Comment: Share some actual json for an object, also there are some parameter stateid and statename, are these referred by countryname and id ?

Comment: @MTahir i have posted actual values now help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code get you result

```
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(json_url);
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            JSONArray countryMasterEntity= json.getJSONArray("countryMasterEntity");

            if(countryMasterEntity!=null)
            {
            // looping through All Contacts
            for(int i = 0; i < countryMasterEntity.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = countryMasterEntity.getJSONObject(i);
                Cursor cr = db.rawQuery("select * from `country` where `id`='"+c.getString("id")+"'",null);

                    String query=
                "Insert into country(id,countryname,createdate,isactive)"+
                "values("+
                c.getString("id")+",'"+
                c.getString("countryname")+"','"+
                c.getString("createdate")+"','"+
                c.getString("isactive")
                +"')";
                    db.execSQL(query);
                Log.d("Insert", query);

                cr.close();
            }
            }
```

Comment: I think you are missing an if condition after the select query, only insert if your cursor `cr` count is zero.

Comment: @Vijay Vala Thanks for answer it was useful