# How to parse json string that has parent and child relationships

Tags: android, json, gson

I am new in parsing json, please help me out. I am requesting from the webserver a list of categories with a parameter "level" which can have a value of 1,2,3 and so on...

**Here is the example of the response of level 1:**

```
  "result": {
        "1214": {
          "name": "Automotive",
          "childs": {
            "2074": "Motorcycle Gear / Accessories",
            "2075": "Accessories",
            "2076": "Car Audio"
          }
        }
}
```

**And here is the example response of level 2:**

```
  "result": {
        "1214": {
          "name": "Automotive",
          "childs": {
            "2074": "Motorcycle Gear / Accessories",
            "2075": "Accessories",
            "2076": {
              "name": "Car Audio",
              "childs": {
                "2077": "Speakers & Subwoofers",
                "2078": "Head Units",
                "2079": "AV Systems",
                "2080": "Amplifiers",
                "2084": "Car Audio Accessories"
              }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

As you can see "Car Audio" that has an id/key "2076" has a child now on level 2. How to make parser that is flexible regarding the levels? I am using GSON also in parsing data, but I dont have an idea how to apply it with this format.
Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you so much

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: More importantly, what is the actual question?

Comment: Try using android volley for GSON responses / parsing. https://github.com/ogrebgr/android_volley_examples

Parsing json could be of JSONArray or JSONObject. In your case its a JSONArray inside a JSONArray inside is a JSONObject. You can parse JSONArray with loops and inside the loop you retrieve the objects. If there are no JSONArrays then you can retrieve the JSONObject directly.

Comment: Consider recursion: parse_child -> go through elements check if has childs -> parse_child

Comment: Try This Article :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23126942/how-to-parse-multiple-arrays-from-single-json-object-and-store-them-in-sqlite-da/23129309#23129309

Comment: Refer this link : http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html

Comment: @Mike Yes ill try to execute that. But I think pmod is correct also with using recursion. Ill try to build up a code and get back to you guys. Thank you so much.